# How to disable EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, disabled-input

How can I disable typing in an `EditText` field in Android?

Comment: Disable Keyboard on input in EditText ?

Comment: There are two editText fields.First is for entering email.if the email is valid then the second editText field is to be enabled.but the problem is while typing an invalid email and clicking on the next button on the soft keyboard it goes to the second text field and can enter data eventhough i've made edittext.setEnabled(false).i am using android 2.3.1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think its a bug in android..It can be fixed by adding this patch :)
Check these links 
[question 1](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2771)
and
[question 2](http://code.google.com/p/android-fixes/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Flibrary%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Hope it will be useful.

Comment: For those who'd rather see the code right here rather than use a hyperlink:

`editText.setEnabled(false);`, in combination with `editText.setFocusable(false);` will achieve this.

Comment: The same works with XML: `android:enabled="false"` and `android:focusable="false"`. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 72):

you can use `EditText.setFocusable(false)` to disable editing
`EditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` to enable editing;

Comment: This was my issue. I  assumed that after `setFocusable(false)` I could just flip  setFocusable(true)... not the case. Setting `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 49):

In code:

```java
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Kotlin:

```
editText.isEnabled = false
```

Or, in XML:

```xml
android:enabled="false"
```

Answer (score 15):

You can try the following method :

```java
private void disableEditText(EditText editText) {
    editText.setFocusable(false);
    editText.setEnabled(false);
    editText.setCursorVisible(false);
    editText.setKeyListener(null);
    editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
}
```

Enabled EditText :

[image: Enabled EditText]

Disabled EditText :

[image: Disabled EditText]

It works for me and hope it helps you.

Comment: good answer but it can be improved by removing the line in which the background color is being change and add  editText.setKeyListener(null);

Answer (score 14):

Assuming `editText` is you `EditText` object:

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 12):

Just set focusable property of your edittext to "false" and you are done.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextInput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:cursorVisible="true">
    </EditText>
```

Below options doesn't work

In code:

`editText.setEnabled(false);`
Or, in XML:
`android:editable="false"`

Answer (score 7):

```
Edittext edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
edittext.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 6):

Enable:

```
private void enableEditText() {
    mEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mEditText.setFocusable(true);
    mEditText.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Disable:

```
private void disableEditText() {
    mEditText.setEnabled(false);
    mEditText.setFocusable(false);
    mEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write `edittext.setInputType(0)` if you want to show the edittext but not input any values

Comment: This is a great answer - it keeps the edit text looking the same

Answer (score 2):

To disable a edittext in android:

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

The below code disables the EditText in android

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: just set focusable property of your edittext to "false" and you are done.


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextInput"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:cursorVisible="true">
        </EditText>

<!-- end snippet -->

Answer (score 2):

```
edittext.setFocusable(false); 
edittext.setEnabled(false);

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
  //removes on screen keyboard
```

Answer (score 1):

According to me...if you have already declared the `edittext` in the XML file and set the property in the XML file `"android:enabled=false"` and disable at runtime to it at that time in java file adding only 2 or 3 lines

1. First create the object
2. Declare EditText et1;
3. Get by id

   `et1 = (EditText) FindViewById(R.id.edittext1);`
    `et1.setEnabled(false);`

You can do enable or disable to every control at run time by java file and design time by XML file.

Answer (score 1):

The XML `editable` property is deprecated since [API LEVEL 15](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputType).

You should use now the `inputType` property with the value `none`.
But there is a bug that makes this functionality useless.

[Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37062549) you can follow the issue status.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in parent:

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/menu_2_zawezanie_rl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/menu_2_horizontalScrollView"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/rame">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/menu2_et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/menu2_ibtn"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/filtruj" >
</EditText>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menu2_ibtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_btn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `inputType` attribute to none in your layout.xml file under EditText

Comment: this do nothing

Answer (score 0):

try this Kotlin code,

`editField.isEnabled = !editField.isEnabled`

Comment: That's toggling, not disabling.

Answer (score -2):

Right click the text area and untick the editable option:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Nuwan Bandara. Your answer is related to JTextArea and not EditText, which is from Android Framework. It is unlikely that you are providing an answer for this question.