# Android cannot disable cut copy paste

Tags: android

I can't disable copy paste option. on samsung galaxy S2, if i click on edittext, a arrow will come and on click on that arrow, all options are coming. onCreateContextMenu has not been called. within onUserInteration, I am just clearing clipboard info using setText() method, on emulator it is working, but not on real device. Please give me the idea. I am trying for hours, but unable to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

See
[How to disable edittext in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879250/how-to-disable-edittext-in-android)

You can additionally set your edittext to `android:editable="false"`

Comment: Will work just fine, only I believe Saravana still want the user to be able to insert text by the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: @Thomas K : Pieter is right. I want to disable only cut. copy and paste option. but editable

Answer (score 0):

Add this to for your edittext for which you want to disable copy paste  option.

```
  edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
                }

                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
                }

                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
                }

                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For disable Copy paste, You need to stop selection and then insertion.
Use below code, its 100% working code.

```
   //This disable the paste 
    editText.setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            menu.clear();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });

    //This Disable selection of text
    editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            menu.clear();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
    editText.setLongClickable(false);
    editText.setTextIsSelectable(false);
```

Answer (score -2):

You might want to check out this question
[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext)

Apparently by catching the long touch event you can prevent the copy paste tools from activating like this:

```
OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) 
    {
        // prevent context menu from being popped up, so that user
        // cannot copy/paste from/into any EditText fields.
        return true;
    }
};
```

Then set the onLongClickListener you just created on the EditText like this:

```
myEditTextView.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
```

Comment: it's not worked. I already tried it. Because on device(galaxy s2), if you click, a cursor will be opened, if you click on the curosr then option will be opened in popup. In this scenario, this method will not be called.