# Android-copy/paste disable

Tags: android, copy-paste

How to disable default copy/paste which appears on longpress/double-click/clickingoneditarrow of edittext in android?? Is there any way to override copy function of default contextmenu

Comment: You can go through these links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333160/android-not-disable-cut-copy-paste

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/I2mh75F8cGY

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI provide an EditText with a method myEditText.disableCopyAndPaste().

**And it's works on old API** :) !